# Beaglebone Black CAN bus communication using Simulink

Tags: simulink, beagleboneblack, can-bus

Does anybody know if it is possible to use CAN communication with beaglebone black when programming with Simulink??

We need Simulink for prototyping so, it is paramount to be able to program with this software.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is [vehicle network toolbox](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vnt/ug/build-can-communication-simulink-models.html)which can provide you that but for code generation you have to make your own interface

Comment: Hi Umar, thanks for your answer. Could you please give me some more details about this question?? The question is, can I completelly set a CAN communication with my beaglebone black just by using Simulink blocks?? Or do I need to write my C code function to set all the details requiered by a CAN communication?? Thanks in advance.